# Compund Inequality with Reciprocal $0<(2x-4)^{-1}<\frac{1}{2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I need help with this exercise: $0<(2x-4)^{-1}<\frac{1}{2}$.

$$0<(2x-4)^{-1}<\frac{1}{2}$$

$$0<\frac{1}{2x-4}<\frac{1}{2}$$

I separate this into two inequalities:

1. $0<\frac{1}{2x-4}$
2. $\frac{1}{2x-4}<\frac{1}{2}$

The first one I had no problem solving it.

$$0<\frac{1}{2x-4}$$

By the Reciprocal Property of inequalities

$$0<2x-4$$

$$4<2x$$

$$\frac{4}{2}<\frac{2x}{2}$$

$$2<x$$

$$x>2$$

Is the second that I have a problem with. Is there a way to solve it without using a sign chart/table? I do know how to do it with a sign chart/table. I just want to know if there is another way to do it that is not the sign table.

Comment: If $0 < a < b$ then $0< \frac 1b < \frac 1a$ so just do $0 < \frac 1{2x-4} < \frac 12$ so $0 < 2 < 2x-4$.  So just solve $2< 2x-4$ $6 < 2x$ so $6\frac 12< 2x \frac 12$ so $3 < x$.  That's it.

Answer (score 3):

As you have correctly concluded, one must have that $x > 2$.

Under such condition, $2x - 4 > 0$.

Hence we can multiply both sides by it so that we obtain an equivalent inequation:

\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{2x - 4} < \frac{1}{2} & \Longleftrightarrow 2 < 2x - 4\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow 2x > 6\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow x > 3
\end{align*}

So the solution set to such problem is given by $S = (3,+\infty)\cap(2,+\infty) = (3,+\infty)$.

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: The thing is that I thought that the reciprocal property can be only applied when there is zero involved. I did that way you did and got that answer. But when I do it with the sign chart I get $(-∞,2)\cup(3,∞)$. That's also what I get when putting it in Symbolab.

Comment: @gi2302 the $(-\infty,2)$ cannot be a solution (take $x = 1$ for instance). That is because we have a system of inequations. You can check out the solution set at [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=0+%3C+1%2F%282x+-4%29+%3C+1%2F2), for instance, which coincides with the solution set I propose. If you still have any questions, please let me know.

Comment: I'm sorry... I must specify that the solution $(-∞,2)\cup(3,∞)$ I said was just for the 2nd inequality (not for the compound)   when I do it with the sign chart. That's what I was doubting applying to the second one the reciprocal property because when doing it I got $(3,∞)$ which is different from $(-∞,2)\cup(3,∞)$.

Comment: When $(2x - 4)^{-1} > 0$? That happens exactly when $x > 2$. So the solution set (according to your reasoning) is given by $((-\infty,2)\cup(3,+\infty))\cap(2,+\infty) = (3,+\infty)$, and we are done. Hopefully this helps!

Answer (score 1):

$$0<(2x-4)^{-1}<\frac{1}{2}$$

$$2<(2x-4)<\infty$$

$$6<2x<\infty$$
$$3<x<\infty$$

Answer (score 1):

If you had $\frac 1{2x-4} < \frac 12$ you'd have a difficulty because you don't know if $\frac 1{2x-4}$ is positive or negative.

!BUT!  you are *GIVEN* that $0 < \frac 1{2x-4}$.

There's no reason to separate it into two inequalities... just take it as a single inequality.

$0 < \frac 1{2x-4} < \frac 12 \iff \frac 1{2x-4}$ is positive and $\frac 1{2x-4} < \frac 12$.

So because $\frac 1{2x-4}$ is given to be positive we have reciprocal law $2x-4 > 2$.

That's all we need.

..... alternatively we should be comfortable with $0 < a < b\implies 0 < \frac 1b < \frac 1a$ is a common rule that out to be second nature.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align*}
0<(2x-4)^{-1}<\frac{1}{2}\\ \\
\implies 
0<\frac{1}{2x-4}<\frac{1}{2}\\ \\
\implies  0< 2< 2x-4\\ \\
\implies  4< (2)+4< (2x-4) + 4 \\ \\
\implies  4< 6< 2x \\
\implies 2< 3< x\\
\implies 3< x\\
\end{align*}